# how to do an asynchronous task for log in activity?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

```
 public static boolean SendMessage(final String response) 
{

    OutputStream out;
    try {
        out = socket.getOutputStream();
        writeResponse(out,response);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        mRun=true;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
```

here is my code for sending login message to tcp socket. I want to perform an asynchronous task for this activity. How can i do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try code like this and execute `new MyAsync().execute();` whenever you want send sms

```
public class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        return SendMessage(response);
    }

}

public static boolean SendMessage(final String response) {

    OutputStream out;
    try {
        out = socket.getOutputStream();
        writeResponse(out, response);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        mRun = true;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: ok fine ..onPostexcute i want to close the opertaion. also onPreExecute i want to call the response.

Comment: which operation you want to close and what do you mean by call response ?